# error while converting [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] in NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios

```
NSString *SocialAuthToken = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];

NSDictionary *postContent = @{ @"LoginType" :LoginType, @"SocialAuthToken" : SocialAuthToken, @"Password" : @"123", @"Info" : DictInfo};

NSLog(@"%@",postContent);

NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postContent                                                            options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Comment: So you're just putting the `code`  here. We don't understand your `iOS` environment. Are you using iOS 1.0? or 10? Put more details.

Answer (score 0):

get `tokenString`  from `FBSDKAccessToken`.

```
 NSString *SocialAuthToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];
```